# Pick out specific menu item from code

Tags: menus

I'm using this bit of code to generate a menu:

```
          <div id="menu">
  <?php $args = array(
    'depth'        => 1,
    'show_date'    => '',
    'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
    'child_of'     => 0,
    'exclude'      => '426, 508',
    'include'      => '',
    'title_li'     => __(''),
    'echo'         => 1,
    'authors'      => '',
    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'link_before'  => '',
    'link_after'   => '',
    'walker' => '' ); ?>
    <ul><div class="menu-button"><?php wp_list_pages( $args, 'sort_column=menu_order' ); ?></div></ul>
    </div>
```

It's generating the menu fine but one of the links I need it to goto another page.

Is it possible to pick out that page by ID and tell it to goto a different address? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using the [Page Links To](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-to/) plugin to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its a simple one liner if you want to use jQuery:

```
jQuery('#page-id').attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: This will affect the way all the other links work though.

Comment: not if you put a specific page id as a selector!